# convert varchar to int using sql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
ResultSet rss=st.executeQuery("select CONVERT(INT,Mark) as marks,sum(marks) as Totall  from groupperformance where Date between '"+fromdate+"' and '"+todate+"' and GName='"+GroupName+"'");
```

I am using above query for converting varchar column to integer and than find the sum of the column but in eclipse console it show the error 
**Exceptioncom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT,Mark) as marks,sum(marks) as Totall  from groupperformance where Date betwee' at line 1**

what can I do for convert varchar column values to integer and perform the sum() function to get the result

I know this is simple question but I need help.some one kindly help me to out from this problem.

Sorry for my poor english

Thanks in advance

Comment: I googled "mysql convert syntax". [This was the top result](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html). It appears as though you didn't expend any effort in researching this for yourself before you came here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See proper use of convert in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)
`convert('2', SIGNED)`
or
`cast('2' as SIGNED)`